# Attribute error from an object that isn't called upon

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-class

I am working on a Mastermind game in python, and one of my classes is called the Game class. This runs a 'setup' of the game as such (like finding the player count, player names etc.). However, one of my methods which checks the name inputted against a player list previously defined/stored in a separate class is bringing up an AttributeError when I try to append the name to a new list created in my Game class. This is what my Game class currently looks like:

```
class WorldOfMastermind:
    """WOM class - Runs whole game, takes results from other classes and stores them (namely players and their scores)"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__playerList = []
        self.__playerDetails = dict()
        
    def run(self):
        """Run method - holds the menu screen - allows for the user to add player, show scores, play game or quit"""
        cpuNames = ComputerPlayer.addDetails(self)
        self.__playerList.extend((cpuNames))
        start = input('What would you like to do?\n (r) register a new user\n (s) show the score board\n (p) play a game\n (q) quit\n')
        if start == 'r':
            tempName = HumanPlayer.addDetails(self)
            for i in self.__playerList:
                if i == tempName:
                    print('')
                    print('Sorry, that name already exists')
                    print('')
                    self.run()
            self.__playerList.append(tempName)
            self.__playerDetails[tempName] = [0, 0, float(0)]
            print('Welcome,', tempName + '!')
            print('')
            self.run()

        elif start == 's':
            self.printScoreBoard() 

        elif start == 'p':
            print('Let\'s play the game of Mastermind!')
            Game.startPrep(self, self.__playerList)

        elif start == 'q':
            print('Thank you for playing the World of Mastermind!')
            exit()
        else:
            print('\nSorry, that is an invalid input')
            print('')
            self.run()
    

    def printScoreBoard(self):
        """ Print the scoreboard by iterating through the dictionary """
        print('=====================================')
        print('Name             Score Games Average ')
        print('=====================================')
        for i in self.__playerDetails:
            print('{:<15} '.format(i), '{:>5}'.format(self.__playerDetails[i][0]), '{:>5}'.format(self.__playerDetails[i][1]), '{:>7}'.format(self.__playerDetails[i][2]))
        print('=====================================\n')   
        self.run()

class Game:
    """Begin the initialization of the game and return results to WOM class"""
    def __init__(self, playerCount):
        self.__playerCount = playerCount
        self.__playingList = []

    def startPrep(self, playerList):
        """Prepares the game"""
        Game.getPlayerCount(self)
        Game.getPlayerNames(self, playerList)

    def getPlayerCount(self):
        """Gathers the number of players"""
        while True:
            try:
                self.__playerCount = int(input('How many players (2-4)?'))
            except ValueError:
                print('Only numbers allowed')
            else:
                if self.__playerCount < 2 or self.__playerCount > 4:
                    print('Player count must be between 2-4 inclusive')
                else:
                    break
    
    def getPlayerNames(self, playerList):
        """Gathers names of players and puts them into a list"""
        while True:
            if self.__playerCount == 2:
                while True:
                    player1 = input('What is the name of player #1?')
                    if player1 in playerList:
                        print('successful')
                        self.__playingList.append(player1)
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Invalid username')

                while True:
                    player2 = input('What is the name of player #2?')
                    if player2 in playerList:
                        if player2 not in self.__playingList:
                            print('successful')
                            self.__playingList.append(player2)
                            break
                        else:
                            print(player2, 'is already in the game.')
                    else:
                        print('Invalid username')
            break
```

Where I feel the error is coming from is in the calling of the getPlayerNames method. As it takes a parameter (the player list from another class), this is purely to check that the name inputted is actually in the game, and if so it prints 'successful' (which it does) but when trying to append the inputted name into the new 'playingList' it brings up the error. I'm not sure why this is as the append line doesn't have any need to reference attributes from another class. Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Is that exactly how your file looks?  Because everything after the "class" line should be indented one spot.  Once I do that, your code runs correctly for me.  I do wonder why you pass a player count to `__init__` and a list of players to `getPlayerName`, when you promptly ignore both values and read from the terminal.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't know why, but almost everyone has a problem pasting code, and the first line is never outdented properly. I just fix it routinely.

Comment: Don't write `Game.getPlayerCount(self)`.  Write `self.getPlayerCount()`.  Same with the next line.

Comment: self.__playingList.append(player1)
AttributeError: 'WorldOfMastermind' object has no attribute '_Game__playingList' I didn't want to put all my code in because I didn't want it looking too confusing, but I can add the WorldOfMastermind class if you'd like

Comment: What is `WorldOfMastermind`?

Comment: @Barmar it is another class which currently stores the playerList

Comment: How are you calling this?  I'm betting you called `Game.getPlayerName` instead of `game = Game()` / `game.startPrep(['name1','name2'])`, as you need to.

Comment: You're not calling your methods the proper way to be able to access private attributes.

Comment: @TimRoberts If i change it to self.getPlayerCount() it brings up the same attributeError

Comment: What I'm saying is that the code you're using to CALL this (which you have not shown) is wrong.  See my answer below, which works.

Comment: I see, I will edit my post to include my mastermind class so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, formatted as below..  If I run the following, it asks for the player count and makes sure the names you give are in the eligible player list.

```
class Game:
    """Begin the initialization of the game and return results to WOM class"""
    def __init__(self, playerCount=0):
        self.__playerCount = playerCount
        self.__playingList = []

    def startPrep(self, eligible):
        """Prepares the game"""
        self.getPlayerCount()
        self.getPlayerNames(eligible)

    def getPlayerCount(self):
        """Gathers the number of players"""
        while True:
            try:
                self.__playerCount = int(input('How many players (2-4)?'))
            except ValueError:
                print('Only numbers allowed')
            else:
                if self.__playerCount < 2 or self.__playerCount > 4:
                    print('Player count must be between 2-4 inclusive')
                else:
                    break

    def getPlayerNames(self, playerList):
        """Gathers names of players and puts them into a list"""
        for i in range(self.__playerCount):
            while True:
                s = 'What is the name of player #%d? '%(i+1)
                player = input(s)
                if player in playerList:
                    print('successful')
                    self.__playingList.append(player)
                    break
                else:
                    print('Invalid username')

g = Game()
g.startPrep(['bob','bill'])
```

Comment: Okay I see, I just didn't create a variable which called the class, instead I had tried to call directly to the function from another class. This now works for me. Thanks